# MD5 hashing produces different results on different pages in ASP:NET

Tags: asp.net, md5

I am building a simple password protected website. I am using the following function for the calculation of MD5 that I found on stackoverflow

```
protected string CalculateMd5Hash(string input)
        {
            // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input 
            var md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes); // step 2, convert byte array to hex string 
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

I have a registeration page and a login page. When the user registers I use the above function to hash the password.

```
var user = new User
    {
        username = txtUsername.Text,
        password = CalculateMd5Hash(txtPassword.Text),

    };
db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

In the login page I check the database for the user and the password to see if they match

```
var queryUserExists = (from u in db.Users
                       where u.username == txtUsername.Text && u.password == CalculateMd5Hash(txtPassword.Text)
                       select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

My problem is the MD5 hash calculated from both pages are different so they dont match even the string is the same. I dont understand why this happens. How can I fix this issue? Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: Where is this method CalculateMd5Hash written?

Comment: It is on every page that uses that function.

Comment: I would recommend using a static class or interface to have a single copy.

Comment: I tried it now with a single static function in a class and no change so far. Still displays different MD5 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. Apperantly the registration page somehow creates an empty string when I press submit and the database saves the MD5 of the empty string (D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E).

It is now fixed.